# I would like to represent the title and gender variables, in my SAS table, as numbers. How do I do this in SAS?

Tags: sas

I would like to represent the title and gender variables as numbers. What code do I need to add to do this?

```
DATA test;
INPUT title$ gender$ name$ age;
CARDS;
Mr Male Micheal 20
Mrs Female Stephanie 25
Mr Female Linda 30
Dr Male James 40
Dr Female Jane 45;
run;
```

Below is my attempt at the question. However something is wrong because the title and gender variables does not change!

```
proc format library = Work;
value $title_ 'Mr' = 1 'Mrs' = 2 'Dr' = 3;
value $gender_ 'Male' = 1 'Female' = 2;    
run;

OPTIONS FMTSEARCH = (Work);

data test;
format $title $title_;
set test;
run;
```

Comment: You can use a character format to do this:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n19px1npxeydvhn1xx9acadcm0vv.htm

Comment: Is this a homework problem ? Do you know apriori all the title and gender textual values you will encounter -- if so, what are they, and what numeric values will you be assigning them ?  Is the numeric representation 'temporary' for the duration of a program run through, or a more permanent duration in which other programs and users will need to know the numeric meanings ?  What kind of numbers ? Monotonic sequence identities ? Can you use the hexadecimal number created by interpreting the hex sequence of the ascii codes ?

Comment: @Richard No, this is not a homework problem. This is for work! I have added my attempt at the solution above, but something is still wrong! I am not sure what it is! Can you advise please?

Comment: @user667489 I have added my attempt at the solution above, but something is still wrong! I am not sure what it is! Can you advise please?

Comment: And a much more complicated example here: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/6c885f6aea18dbd6caf8

Comment: If you continue down the number rabbit hole, one twist is to code an INVALUE statement in Proc FORMAT to create a custom informat that can be used with an INPUT statement or the INPUT function.  In such a twist, the data values for title/gender would be numeric.  You can also code an inversing numeric format that maps the numbers back to the original texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there - you just have slightly wrong syntax for your format statement. This is your current format statement:

```
format $title $title_;
```

Here's a corrected one. I've extended it to apply your gender format as well:

```
  format title $title_. gender $gender_.;
```

It is not necessary to overwrite a dataset to apply a format, i.e.

```
data mydata;
  set mydata;
  format ...;
run;
```

You can apply one directly by using proc datasets instead of writing a data step like the one above, e.g.

```
proc datasets lib = work;
  modify test;
  format title $title_. gender $gender_.;
  run;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have one last question. In the example I gave there was only 3 distinct titles and 2 distinct genders. So it was easy to re-label these variable elements into numbers. However if I had 100+ distinct elements within a variable, is there an efficient way to re-label these elements from 1 to 100?

Comment: Yes, use CNTLIN data set and proc format. See Example 8 in this paper about creating a format from a data set. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/001-30.pdf